# Download a web page HTML as a UTF-8 string

Tags: html, vb.net, utf-8

I want to download online page's inner html, but when i do that, characters like **šđčćž** are replaced by **Ä‡¡** and so on.

Code i am using:

```
Dim sourceString As String = New System.Net.WebClient().DownloadString("SomeWebPage")
TextBox1.Text = sourceString
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You probably have to download bytes then use `Encoding` class to convert to UTF8 :

```
Async Function GetHtmlString(address As String) As Task(Of String)
    Using client As New WebClient
        Dim bytes  = Await client.DownloadDataTaskAsync(address)
        Dim s  = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(bytes)
        return s
    End Using
End Function
```

An even simpler way thanks to @dave's comment:

```
Async Function GetHtmlString(address As String) As Task(Of String)
    Using client As New WebClient
        client.Encoding = Encoding.UTF8
        Dim s  = Await client.DownloadStringTaskAsync(address)
        return s
    End Using
End Function
```

Usage example:

```
Imports System.Net
Imports System.Text

Public Class Form1
    Private Async Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        Dim s = Await GetHtmlString("http://www.radiomerkury.pl/")
    End Sub

    Async Function GetHtmlString(address As String) As Task(Of String)
        Using client As New WebClient
            client.Encoding = Encoding.UTF8
            Dim s = Await client.DownloadStringTaskAsync(address)
            Return s
        End Using
    End Function
End Class
```

Comment: Or just set the [Encoding](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webclient.encoding(v=vs.110).aspx) property of the WebClient.

Comment: I guess that is answer i want, but i don't know C# so i could translate it to VB.Net...

Comment: Sorry I've pasted VB code now :) And I guess @dave is right !

Comment: It doesn't seems to work for me...Anyone tested it? Thank you anyway.

Comment: Give an example of a web page to download.

Comment: It's just website with lots of text that contains **šđčćž** etc.

Comment: look at my edit, it's a page in Polish, looks fine to me.

Comment: Have you tested it? :|

Comment: Yes I have but you know I don't speak Polish so it just looks fine to me :) That's why I've asked you for an example web site.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/121789/discussion-between-kibi-brat-and-aybe).

Answer (score 0):

Kibi, I think you're way, way, way off the mark here.  I don't see how VB.NET is going to help you with this kind of thing.  Below is a simple, and intuitive, Excel & VBA solution.  I hope that helps you achieve your goal.

```
Sub DumpData()

Set IE = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")
IE.Visible = True

URL = "http://finance.yahoo.com/q?s=sbux&ql=1"

'Wait for site to fully load
IE.Navigate2 URL
Do While IE.Busy = True
   DoEvents
Loop

RowCount = 1

With Sheets("Sheet1")
   .Cells.ClearContents
   RowCount = 1
   For Each itm In IE.document.all
      .Range("A" & RowCount) = itm.tagname
      .Range("B" & RowCount) = itm.ID
      .Range("C" & RowCount) = itm.classname
      .Range("D" & RowCount) = Left(itm.innertext, 1024)

      RowCount = RowCount + 1
   Next itm
End With
End Sub
```